# How to change "Next" button to "Submit" on last tab only

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have three tabs in my `form`, and I want to change the **Next** button to **Submit** on my last tab only.

This should be done dynamically, for example if I add a fourth tab later, then the button on the fourth tab should be changed.

Here is my code:

```html
 <form id="commentForm" id="save" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('home/save_student');?>">
  <div id="rootwizard" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-wizard-steps">
      <ul class="wizard-steps">
        <li class="" data-target="#step1"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="step">1</span><span class="title">Basic information</span></a></li>
        <li data-target="#step2" class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="step">2</span><span class="title">Parents information</span></a></li>
        <li data-target="#step3" class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="step">3</span><span class="title">Other information</span></a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content transparent">
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1"> <br>
        <h4 class="semi-bold">Step 1 - <span class="light">Basic Information</span></h4>
        <br>
        <div class="row form-row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" name="name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" name="email">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Date Of Birth" class="input-append date form-control" name="dob">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Roll No" class="form-control" name="roll_no">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Date Of Admission" name="doa" class="input-append date form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Date for Status" name="status_date" class="input-append date form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"> <br>
          <h4 class="semi-bold">Step 2 - <span class="light">Parents Information</span></h4>
          <br>
          <div class="row form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control " name="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3"> <br>
          <h4 class="semi-bold">Step 3 - <span class="light">Other Information</span></h4>
          <br>
          <div class="row form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control " name="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class=" wizard wizard-actions">
          <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Previous</a></li>
          <li class="next"><a href="javascript:;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**My Controller name is `save_student`.**

Comment: I can only see one 'Next' button in your code.

Comment: I added the save button as well but it isn't working the way it should :(

Comment: then use wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Javascript for that, just store tabs in array like `let tabs=[‘tab1’, ‘tab2’, ‘tab3’]` and maintain the currentTab variable which will tell you the current tab user is on. Now when your currentTab gets equal to tabs[tabs.length-1], you need to submit that form.

Answer (score 0):

I've used click event to track the tab button clicks then change the text of the next button accordingly:

```js
//get tab buttons seletors
let tabs = document.getElementsByClassName('wizard-steps')[0].getElementsByTagName("LI");

//attach a click event to it
for (i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
  tabs[i].addEventListener("click", getCurrentTab);
}


function getCurrentTab(event){
//get the #tab{i}
  let path = event.path[1].href;
  let currentTab = path.split('#')[1];
  
  //check if this is the last tab
  if(currentTab == ('tab' + tabs.length)){
    //get the button on the last tab
    let actions = document.getElementsByClassName("wizard-actions")[0];
    let lastLi = actions.getElementsByClassName("next")[0];
    let lastButton = lastLi.getElementsByClassName('btn-primary')[0];
    lastButton.innerHTML = 'Submit';
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="commentForm" id="save" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('home/save_student');?>">
    <div id="rootwizard" class="col-md-12">
      <div class="form-wizard-steps">
        <ul class="wizard-steps">
          <li class="" data-target="#step1"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab"><span class="step">1</span><span class="title">Basic information</span></a></li>
          <li data-target="#step2" class=""><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab"><span class="step">2</span><span class="title">Parents information</span></a></li>
          <li data-target="#step3" class=""><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab"><span class="step">3</span><span class="title">Other information</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-content transparent">
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1"> <br>
          <h4 class="semi-bold">Step 1 - <span class="light">Basic Information</span></h4>
          <br>
          <div class="row form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" name="name">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" name="email">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Date Of Birth" class="input-append date form-control" name="dob">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Roll No" class="form-control" name="roll_no">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Date Of Admission" name="doa" class="input-append date form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Date for Status" name="status_date" class="input-append date form-control">
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2"> <br>
          <h4 class="semi-bold">Step 2 - <span class="light">Parents Information</span></h4>
          <br>
          <div class="row form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control " name="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
          <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3"> <br>
          <h4 class="semi-bold">Step 3 - <span class="light">Other Information</span></h4>
          <br>
          <div class="row form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control " name="">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <ul class=" wizard wizard-actions">
          <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Previous</a></li>
          <li class="next"><a href="javascript:;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**NOTE**: Please, use the html from my code since the HTML you shared had some typos and repeated selectors.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your markup is utterly broken.

- you can't have two `id` attributes on the same element
- you should take extra care where you close each element. For example, in your current markup, the first tab also contains tabs 2 and 3.
- one of your tabs should be `active` (the one which you want shown when the tabs are rendered)
- if you want to make use of Bootstrap tabs plugin, your tab controls should have the markup of any of [their examples](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#tabs). That's because they rely on internal classes, such as `.nav-tabs`, `.nav-items` and `.nav-link` to activate and make the tabs work.
- also, in your example, 2nd and 3rd controls have the same target: tab 2.
- instead of using `<br>` tags, use the provided padding and margin utilities: for example, `py-3` applied on each of the tab `<h4>`s serve the same purpose as the preceding and following `<br>`.

After you fix all those, you should use the `shown.bs.tab` [event](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#events) and figure out if the tab the user navigated to is the last one. Here's a working example:

```js
$('#formTabs').on('shown.bs.tab', e => {
  $('#commentForm .wizard-actions li:last-child a').text(
    $(e.target).closest('li').index() + 1 === $('#formTabs>li').length ?
    'Submit' :
    'Next'
  );
})
```

```css
#commentForm {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form id="commentForm" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('home/save_student');?>">
  <div id="rootwizard" class="col-md-12">
    <div class="form-wizard-steps">
      <ul class="wizard-steps nav nav-tabs px-3" id="formTabs">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link active">
            <span class="step">1</span>
            <span class="title">Basic information</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">
            <span class="step">2</span>
            <span class="title">Parents information</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab" class="nav-link">
            <span class="step">3</span>
            <span class="title">Other information</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content transparent">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
        <h4 class="semi-bold py-3">Step 1 - <span class="light">Basic Information</span></h4>
        <div class="row form-row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" name="name">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control" name="email">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Date Of Birth" class="input-append date form-control" name="dob">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Roll No" class="form-control" name="roll_no">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Date Of Admission" name="doa" class="input-append date form-control">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Date for Status" name="status_date" class="input-append date form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <h4 class="semi-bold py-3">Step 2 - <span class="light">Parents Information</span></h4>
        <div class="row form-row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control " name="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <h4 class="semi-bold py-3">Step 3 - <span class="light">Other Information</span></h4>
        <div class="row form-row">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control " name="">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <ul class=" wizard wizard-actions">
      <li class="previous"><a href="javascript:;" class="btn">Previous</a></li>
      <li class="next"><a href="javascript:;" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Next</a></li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</form>
```

In the above example, `$(e.target).closest('li').index() + 1` is the currently selected tab index (1 based) and `$('#formTabs>li').length` is the total number of tabs.

Which means the rough translation of the script into plain English would be: *"Whenever a tab of `#formTabs` is shown, set the text of `#commentForm .wizard-actions li:last-child a` to `Submit` if the current tab is the last one or to `Next` otherwise."*